# Dynamic Cursor from the procedure argument

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, cursor

I have a procedure that takes an argument. And I want to loop a cursor through the query based on that argument.

For example:

the argument is passed: salary

the cursor should be (select salary from emp) and loop through it.

How should I do that ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like you want the [`open for`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629) dynamic SQL construction.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ARGUMENT VARCHAR(50) = 'salary';
DECLARE @CURSOR_BODY VARCHAR(MAX) = '
declare @variable varchar(max)
declare cur cursor for 
select '+ @argument +  ' from emp
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @variable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
    select @variable
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @variable;
    END
CLOSE cur   
DEALLOCATE cur'

print @cursor_body

EXEC (@CURSOR_BODY)
```

Try sth. like this